# can i use spritebuilder to develop cross platform mobile app?

Tags: mobile, opengl-es, 2d-games, spritebuilder

I wanna develop a game app, which should be platform independent. is spritebuilder a cross platform?

Comment: SpriteBuilder supports development for iOS and OS X plus Android with the Android plugin that is currently in beta (already used to create apps though, it's pretty stable).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, SpriteBuilder exports project files for Xcode limiting development to iOS. Plans are in the works so that SpriteBuilder can export for Android Studio as well, but as of this writing the current version of SpriteBuilder does not support this capability.

If you are still interested in using SpriteBuilder for iOS, you can use Apportable's free service to help translate your Objective-C code to run natively on Android. This will require additional programming and knowledge of another SDK such as Android Studio.

Unity is another free SDK that you can use to publish cross platform games that are 3D, although you will no longer be building truly native Apps for either iOS or Android.

Should this answer be sufficient, please mark "correct answer", else, let me know if there are any further questions you may have.

Comment: You don't need much additional programming knowledge, you can totally run your game straight from Xcode. And Android Studio is an IDE, not an SDK, and all you would need it for is to have a little help while writing your java code if you'll even have any.